# Python: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'mostfrequent' referenced before assignment (KNeighborsClassifier)

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to run KNeighborsClassifer for multiple "k" as follows, but get an error on line where I am doing the "predictions". When I run the same code with k = 1, even multiple times, it works fine. There must be something I don't understand about the sklearn objects here. What is the problem with the code here? Thank you.

My code:

```
accuracy = []
f1score = []
predictions = []
for n in range(10):
    vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
    output = vectorizer.fit_transform(train_data)
    output_dev = vectorizer.transform(dev_data)

    neighbor = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors = n)
    neighbor.fit(output, train_labels)
    predictions = neighbor.predict(output_dev)

    accuracy.append(round(sum(predictions == dev_labels) * 1.0 / len(predictions), 2))
    f1score.append(round(metrics.f1_score(dev_labels, predictions), 2))
print accuracy
print f1score
```

Error message:

```
UnboundLocalError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-99-c3eaa2d9dd70> in <module>()
     17     print f1score
     18 
---> 19 P3()

<ipython-input-99-c3eaa2d9dd70> in P3()
     10         neighbor = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors = n)
     11         neighbor.fit(output, train_labels)
---> 12         predictions = neighbor.predict(output_dev)
     13 
     14         accuracy.append(round(sum(predictions == dev_labels) * 1.0 / len(predictions), 2))

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/neighbors/classification.pyc in predict(self, X)
    160         for k, classes_k in enumerate(classes_):
    161             if weights is None:
--> 162                 mode, _ = stats.mode(_y[neigh_ind, k], axis=1)
    163             else:
    164                 mode, _ = weighted_mode(_y[neigh_ind, k], weights, axis=1)

/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/scipy/stats/stats.pyc in mode(a, axis)
    658         oldcounts = np.maximum(counts, oldcounts)
    659         oldmostfreq = mostfrequent
--> 660     return mostfrequent, oldcounts
    661 
    662 def mask_to_limits(a, limits, inclusive):

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'mostfrequent' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: This error is caused by trying to calculate the mode of an empty array with `scipy.stats.mode([])`. I think in your code it does not make sense to set `n_neighbors = n`. If you look closely, you are actually trying to run a `0-nearest neighbor algorithm` here :)

Comment: That was the only problem with the code, other than I am unnecessarily re-running fit_transform in the loop. Been exclusively working with R over the past 3 months and did not touch Python. Forgot zero indexing. :)